# How to embedd a webserver into CAS webapp release

Tags: java, jetty, maven-3, cas, embedded-jetty

I have tried to run CAS webapp such as an executable WAR, and initially I found out two possible solutions. But there would be a better solution for this?

1) Creating a main class to start a Jetty embedded server and the CAS war file to run;

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.tomcat.InstanceManager;
import org.apache.tomcat.SimpleInstanceManager;
import org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter;
import org.eclipse.jetty.apache.jsp.JettyJasperInitializer;
import org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;
import org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource;

public class CasServerEmbedded {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Create the server
        Server server = new Server(8080);

        // Enable parsing of jndi-related parts of web.xml and jetty-env.xml
        org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Configuration.ClassList classlist = org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Configuration.ClassList
                .setServerDefault(server);
        classlist.addAfter("org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration",
                "org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration", "org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusConfiguration");

        // Create a WebApp
        final WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext();
        webAppContext.setAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir", getScratchDir());
        webAppContext.setAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.ContainerIncludeJarPattern",
                ".*/[^/]*servlet-api-[^/]*\\.jar$|.*/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-.*\\.jar$|.*/.*taglibs.*\\.jar$");
        webAppContext.setAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.containerInitializers", jspInitializers());
        webAppContext.setAttribute(InstanceManager.class.getName(), new SimpleInstanceManager());
        webAppContext.addBean(new ServletContainerInitializersStarter(webAppContext), true);
        webAppContext.setWar("C:\\temp\\cas-server-webapp-4.2.1.war");
        server.setHandler(webAppContext);

        final JdbcDataSource jdbcDataSource = new JdbcDataSource();
        jdbcDataSource.setURL("jdbc:h2:c:\\temp\\teste;mv_store=false");
        jdbcDataSource.setUser("sa");
        jdbcDataSource.setPassword("sa");
        jdbcDataSource.getConnection();

        new org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource(webAppContext, "jdbc/mydatasource", jdbcDataSource);

        server.start();
        server.join();
    }

    /**
     * Establish Scratch directory for the servlet context (used by JSP
     * compilation)
     */
    private static File getScratchDir() throws IOException {
        File tempDir = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
        File scratchDir = new File(tempDir.toString(), "embedded-jetty-jsp");

        if (!scratchDir.exists()) {
            if (!scratchDir.mkdirs()) {
                throw new IOException("Unable to create scratch directory: " + scratchDir);
            }
        }
        return scratchDir;
    }

    /**
     * Ensure the jsp engine is initialized correctly
     */
    private static List<ContainerInitializer> jspInitializers() {
        JettyJasperInitializer sci = new JettyJasperInitializer();
        ContainerInitializer initializer = new ContainerInitializer(sci, null);
        List<ContainerInitializer> initializers = new ArrayList<ContainerInitializer>();
        initializers.add(initializer);
        return initializers;
    }
}
```

2) Using Maven I can execute the goal **jetty:run-war**, which starts the WAR overlay inside Jetty embedded server.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd ">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
    <artifactId>cas-overlay</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <properties>
        <cas.version>4.2.1</cas.version>
        <maven-jetty-plugin.version>9.3.6.v20151106</maven-jetty-plugin.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
            <artifactId>cas-server-webapp</artifactId>
            <version>${cas.version}</version>
            <type>war</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>cas</warName>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <overlays>
                        <overlay>
                            <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
                            <artifactId>cas-server-webapp</artifactId>
                        </overlay>
                    </overlays>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-jetty-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <jettyXml>${basedir}/etc/jetty/jetty.xml</jettyXml>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <systemProperty>
                            <name>org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.maxWait</name>
                            <value>240</value>
                        </systemProperty>
                    </systemProperties>
                    <webApp>
                        <contextPath>/cas</contextPath>
                        <overrideDescriptor>${basedir}/etc/jetty/web.xml</overrideDescriptor>
                    </webApp>
                    <webAppConfig>
                        <allowDuplicateFragmentNames>true</allowDuplicateFragmentNames>
                    </webAppConfig>
                    <jvmArgs>-Dlog4j.configurationFile=/etc/cas/log4j2.xml -Xdebug
                        -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=5000,server=y,suspend=n</jvmArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>cas</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

As you can see, both solutions start CAS into a standalone web server, but what I am trying to reach is something what Jenkins does, a WAR file which can be started by a simple command line: java -jar CAS.war

Is there any way to export that Maven build in a WAR file running via Jetty embedded?

Tks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is automatically provided by CAS v5 and Spring Boot. Do not re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Ok,  but where can I get this CAS 5 version? So far there's only the version 4.2.1 available on Maven.  Is there any roadmap about it?

Comment: There is this: https://github.com/apereo/cas

and this:
https://github.com/apereo/cas/issues (filter by milestone) 

and this:
https://github.com/apereo/cas/milestones

and this:
https://github.com/apereo/cas-overlay-template/tree/5.0

v5 is still in dev. Expect roughness.

Comment: I didn't find anything where is mentioned that CAS v5 will run over Spring Boot. Where have you seen it?

Comment: I have been looking over the code in github and CAS 5 looks awesome running in Spring Boot.  I am really looking forward to it. I saw Spring Cloud + Session + Boot in there...